# How to replicate a matrix into a cube in Armadillo or RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I have a matrix (say A) of dimension (k1, k2). I want to replicate it N times and save it into a 3D array or cube called B. As a result, the dimension of B will be (k1, k2, N).

In R, I did the following to do that:

```
B <- replicate(N, A)
```

I wonder if there is a function in Armadillo that can do that. Or, is looping the only way?

Thank you!

Comment: you should probably initialize the cube then fill it

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid using a loop with the `each_slice()` method, but the cube must still be initialized beforehand:

```cpp
arma::cube B(k1, k2, N);
B.each_slice() = A;
```

which has the advantage of conciseness.